# jstorage set results not persisting

Tags: javascript, jstorage

We are calling jstorage from jquery as in:

`$.jstorage.set("foo","bar object");`

Later on we look for this key "foo" is gone!  Why would this be?  We set breakpoints on the jstorage deleteKey method and it is not being called.

Specifically:

$.jstorage.index()

does not contain "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Good lord I found the answer.  Let's look at the _save method in jstorage.js, used to persist that set call:

```
function _save(){
  _dropOldEvents(); // remove expired events
  try{
    _storage_service.jStorage = JSON.stringify(_storage);
    // If userData is used as the storage engine, additional
    if(_storage_elm) {
      _storage_elm.setAttribute("jStorage",_storage_service.jStorage);
      _storage_elm.save("jStorage");
    }
    _storage_size = _storage_service.jStorage?String(_storage_service.jStorage).length:0;
   }catch(E7){/* probably cache is full, nothing is saved this way*/}
 }
```

So, let's see, in the jstorage library, where is persists its data, if the local storage is full, and  it cannot write, then it simply takes that exception and swallows it.  Ugh!

Could I please have my exceptions?  In our local copy we at least output this to the console log.  But now I know, local storage with its cap of 5 MB on FireFox and 2.5 MB on Chrome, really was too good to be true.  I'm a sad panda.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  This has not been addressed in the main branch, so I removed the try/catch myself in my local copy and handle the error myself.  Hiding fatal errors!!  Ugh.